# Can we use typedef struct node node;

Tags: c, struct, typedef

```
typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}Node;
```

will it make any difference if I use 'node' instead of 'Node'

```
typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}node;
```

Comment: Did you try? Did it (not) work?

Comment: That is just a name.

Comment: It's valid. we can use it.

Answer (score 3):

Tag names for structs, unions, and enums occupy a different name space from other identifiers (including typedef names), so `typedef struct node { ... } node;` is valid.

Struct and union member names occupy yet another namespace, so the following is legal, if ill-advised:

```
typedef struct foo { int foo; } foo;
```

What you *can't* do is something like

```
typedef struct foo {...} foo;
foo foo;
```

since both the typedef name and the variable name occupy the same name space.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is just a name. However most C naming conventions dictate that `typedef` structures are capitalized, so most would prefer `Node`.

Comment: OK, but why'd I use `C++` naming convention in a `C` code (#nothing serious, just for fun). :-)